# Poisson distribution or Normal distribution

Tags: c++, c++11, random, normal-distribution, poisson

If it is needed to generate randoms in [*N*, *M*] range, but with more numbers close to *avg* (*N* <= *avg* <= *M*), which is better to use:

- [`poisson_distribution`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/numeric/random/poisson_distribution) or
- [`normal_distribution`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/numeric/random/normal_distribution)?

Seeing at examples at cppreference pages (at bottom of the pages), they both generate what is needed:

`poisson_distribution` at point `4`:

```
0 *
1 *******
2 **************
3 *******************
4 *******************
5 ***************
6 **********
7 *****
8 **
9 *
10 
11 
12 
13
```

`normal_distribution` at point `5` with standard deviation `2`:

```
-2 
-1 
 0 
 1 *
 2 ***
 3 ******
 4 ********
 5 **********
 6 ********
 7 *****
 8 ***
 9 *
10 
11 
12
```

What to choose? May be something else?

Comment: The better distribution to use is the one that better describes your data.

Comment: @Cyber I need a random distribution for a game (gambling) in [0,1), where it must generate randoms averaging at 0.25.

Comment: But what do the numbers model? Coin tosses? Rolls of the dice? Cards, or roulette, or slot machine cylinders, or something else? The distribution is selected based on what you're trying to describe, not on on the mean and variance.

Comment: @Useless slot machine, 0.25 of [0, 1) is like 4 of 20, 4 is smallest significance symbol on slot machine

Comment: For slot machines, I'd expect the chance of each symbol on a given rotor to be uniformly distributed (each position is equally likely), but the mean or sum of all rotors would use the Bates or Irwin-Hall distribution, respectively. Since neither mean nor sum are exactly how you score a rotor combination, I don't know there's a simple distribution for the overall score - but if you can generate each rotor correctly, maybe it doesn't matter.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can center both distributions in a point that suits your needs.

But if `M` is small, then the Poisson distribution has a 'fat tail', that is, the probability of getting a number above `M` is higher compared to the normal distribution.

In the normal case, you can control this chance via the variance parameter (it can be as small as you want).

The other, rather obvious difference is that Poisson will onli give you positive integers, whreas a Normal Distribution will give any number in the `[N,M]` range.

Plus, when `[N,M]` are large enough, the Poisson converges to a Normal distribution. So even if the Poisson is the right model, the normal approximation won't be so inaccurate.

With this in mind, if the numbers do not simulate a counting process, I would go for the Normal.

Comment: Centering to get the desired mean only works for symmetric distributions, and the Poisson can be quite skewed.  Also, your statement about convergence of Poisson to normal is incorrect.  Poissons aren't expressed in range terms, they have a single parameter lambda which is both the mean and the variance.  If lambda is close to (within lambda of) the lower bound of the range, the result won't look anything at all like a normal regardless of sample size.

Comment: I meant that in both cases he could choose a parameter to make the mean the figure he wanted. In the Poisson case, lambda as you say.
As for the convergence, I assumed N < lambda < M so I impled that lambda went to infinity with the desired range.
As your answer says (+1), none of these distributions is the best suited for a bounded range, but since the OP is choosing between these two, I compared them.

Comment: Why would the range be going to infinity?

Comment: I answered before he clarified he meant using the code for a gambling game, so the range wasn't established. It could be anything. Maybe I hould have asked that before answering.

Comment: It still doesn't necessarily go to normality.  For a standard Poisson (based at zero), if the mean is less than sqrt(lambda) the distribution will be skewed, and therefore not normal.  Shifting the distribution and lambda by N and then letting N go to infinity won't alter the skewness, and since the Poisson has an unbounded upper tail letting M go to infinity plays no role.

Comment: Among other uses, the Poisson gives a better approximation to the binomial distribution when p is very close to zero (or 1) than does the normal approximation.  It's the very fact that the Poisson distribution is shaped differently than the normal that makes it so useful.

Comment: `poisson_distribution` doesn't support shifted Poissons, they are always based at 0. If M > 0 a bigger lambda wolud result in a higher mean (inside `[M,N]`) but still the drawings would be from a 0 based Poisson. Look I'm a newbie here, so if the answer is misleading I'll erase it. None of this distributions is the best for this excercise, I agree. But the OP was comparing these two. For the reasons I exposed, I think the "least worse" choice is a Normal r.v.

Comment: The programmer can shift any distribution by adding a shift constant, so that shouldn't be an issue.  What makes for the best choice depends on the characteristics of the distribution being modeled.  If skewness is relevant, pick a skewed distribution.  But I'm trying to point out that Poisson's don't automagically become normals just because N and M may be large.

Answer (score 3):

Neither choice is great if you need the outcomes on a bounded range.  The normal distribution has infinite tails at both ends, the Poisson distribution has an infinite upper tail.  At a minimum you'd want a truncated form of one of them.  If you're not truncating, note that the normal is always symmetric about its mean while a Poisson can be quite skewed.  The two distributions also differ in the fact that the normal is continuous, the Poisson is discrete, although you can discretize continuous distributions by binning the results.

If you want a discrete set of outcomes on a bounded range, you could try a scaled and shifted [binomial distribution](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Binomial_distribution).  A binomial with parameters `n` and `p` counts how many "successes" you get out of `n` trials when the trials are independent and all yield success with probability `p`.  Make `n = M - N` and shift the outcome by N to get outcomes in the range [N,M].

If you want a continuous range of outcomes, consider a [beta distribution](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Beta_distribution).  You can fudge the parameters to get a wide variety of distribution shapes and dial in the mean to where you want it, and scale+shift it to any range you want.

Answer (score 1):

If you need distribution which is within range (not an infinite or semi-infinite one like normal or Poisson), but have clear maximum, you may try Irwin-Hall one with several degrees of freedom. Say IH(16) will have minimum at 0, maximum at 16 and peak at 8, see http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Irwin%E2%80%93Hall_distribution

Very easy to sample, easy to scale, and you could play with `n` to get peak wider or narrower

Answer (score -2):

I prefer Normal distribution, because it is closer to real life problems, while Poisson distribution is used for special cases only. Choosing N.D makes your problem more general.

Comment: This is an unfounded and inaccurate statement. How could you possibly pick a single distribution and claim that it accurately represents "real life problems". Distributions vary widely because real life systems also vary immensely. The distribution you choose should be carefully selected with your application in mind. Not arbitrarily because "I don't know, it's kind of common I guess".

Comment: As the problem used is a random numbers generation, I assume that N.D is closer.

Comment: @MagedNasan "As the problem used is a random numbers generation..."  What a silly thing to say!  This statement applies equally to any and every other distribution people might want to generate.